# How to pass an object that is calling a method as an argument to the method in Java?

Tags: java, oop, arguments

I have a method called PositionSetter in a class called Ship. It needs a Board object as a parameter. Every Board object is supposed to call the PositionSetter method, and pass itself as an argument. How do I do this? 
Code:

```
public void PositionSetter(Board BattleshipBoard, Ship ship)
{
  //do stuff with BattleshipBoard and ship  
}
```

Again, the object that's calling the above method, is a Board object that needs to pass itself as an argument. Alternatives to my approach are welcome.

Comment: Use `this`... Like `PositionSetter(this, ship);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a ship object 'shipOne' in your Board Class,
you can invoke then its PositionSetter method from Board class as follows:

```
shipOne.PositionSetter(this,shipOne);
```

This answers your question.
However I have the following suggestions:
1.I think its the responsibility of the Board class to set the ships in its position.I don't know why PositionSetter method is there in Ship class.

2.Also I didn't understand the need for ship argument.If its the same ship that is being passed for which the method is called,then you don't have to pass that.
It will be accessible as 'this' in the method anyway.

3.Method names should follow camelCase naming convention.Please refer here:
http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html

Good luck with your BattleShip game!

Answer (score 1):

Try below stuff.

**Main.java**

```
public class Main
{
public static void main(String[] args) {
     Ship ship=new Ship();
     ship.PositionSetter(ship);  // call method inside Ship class
 }
}
```

**Ship.java**

```
public void PositionSetter(Board BattleshipBoard, Ship ship)
{
   //do stuff with BattleshipBoard and ship  
}
```

Comment: Something is wrong with code: where is the missing Board parameter that shall be passed to PositionSetter() method?

Answer (score 0):

I can't understand your means completely.

Just guess.

First,
You can write a interface, such as :

```
public interface ObjInter {
}
```

Then, other object who will call the method must implements this interface, such as :

```
public class Board implements ObjInter {
    ...
}
```

Last, your method can write like this:

```
public void PositionSetter(Board BattleshipBoard, ObjInter obj) {
    //do stuff with BattleshipBoard and ship  
}
```

Whether the above is meet your question?